# How do i delete a main branch?

Tags: git

I initialized a git repo while I was still at the desktop directory before creating a folder for my workspace, all files and folders on the desktop are now tracked and I can't figure out how to delete this. Whenever i try creating a new folder for my workspace on the desktop, the main branch is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you initialize git to a repository/folder, a *.git* hidden folder is created that stores all the tracking information for that repository/folder. Below are the steps to remove git and stop git from tracking the desktop folder.

#### Windows Operating System

---

> 1. Browser to your desktop folder.
> 2. Navigate to 'View' and check the Hidden items
> 3. Delete the *.git* folder as shown in the image below

[image]

---

#### Linux, Mac, or Unix based operating systems

---

Open a terminal and navigate to the directory of your project, i.e. - `cd path_to_your_desktop`.

> **Run this command:**
>
> `rm -rf .git*`

This will remove the Git tracking and metadata from your project like the *.gitignore* files

Answer (score 0):

Simply move git folder to another location, some directory. To do so, find hidden *.git* folder on desktop, and move it with files which you'd like to track to separate repository. For Windows you could see hidden files like this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files-0320fe58-0117-fd59-6851-9b7f9840fdb2.

Then commit changes, because git will consider missing files as deleted. And you will have clean repository.

Comment: Ooh, you've made my day. It has solved my problem. Thanks alot